# Delphi Win32 TXMLDocument can't be instantiated and used from a thread?

Tags: delphi, indy, win32com, indy10, txmldocument

I've been working with an Indy `TIdTCPServer` object and instantiating a `TXMLDocument` object instance during the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event.  I find it quite surprising that I get an exception when `xml.Active` is set to true:

> Microsoft MSXML is not installed

```pascal
procedure TForm4.tcpRXExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  sResponseXML : string;
  xml:IXMLDocument;
begin
  // get message from client
  sResponseXML := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

  xml:=TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  
  // error here:  "Microsoft MSXML is not installed"
  xml.Active:=true;

  xml.Encoding:='UTF-8';

  xml.LoadFromXML(sResponseXML);

  // use the xml document
  
  //AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('... message sent from server :)');
end;
```

Looking deeper, I found that the exception occurs because `TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.TryCoCreateInstance()` is unable to create the correct document object instance despite receiving the same `GuidList` as it received in other parts of the application from the main thread.  I don't understand why the object isn't instantiated if called from the component's thread.

Here's the Embarcadero code where the object should be instantiated:

```pascal
class function TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.TryCoCreateInstance(const GuidList: array of TGUID): IUnknown;
var
  I: Integer;
  Status: HResult;
begin
  for I := Low(GuidList) to High(GuidList) do
  begin
    // never successful if the XML document object was being used from the Execute event handler.
    Status := CoCreateInstance(GuidList[I], nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
      CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IDispatch, Result);
    if Status = S_OK then Exit;
  end;
end;
```

I expect it must have something to do with `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` or `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx), but I don't see why these could be a problem.

Even if that was the cause, how can I use `TXMLDocument` from within that event handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MSXML is a COM-based technology. You need to call `CoInitialize/Ex()` to initialize the COM library in every thread context that accesses COM interfaces. Otherwise, in this case, `CoCreateInstance()` will fail with a `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` error. Delphi's RTL initializes the COM library for you in the main thread, but you have to do it yourself in worker threads, such as those used by `TIdTCPServer`.

By default, `TIdTCPServer` creates a new thread for each client connection. In this case, the *easiest* place to initialize COM would be in the server's `OnConnect` event (since the `OnExecute` event is looped).

```pascal
procedure TForm4.tcpRXConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
end;

procedure TForm4.tcpRXDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  CoUninitialize();
end;
```

However, since `TIdTCPServer` supports thread-pooling, and COM should be initialized only once per thread, the *best* place to initialize COM in this case <sup>1</sup> is directly in each thread's `Execute()` method. To do that, explicitly assign a `TIdSchedulerOfThread`-derived component (`TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault`, `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool`, etc) to the `TIdTCPServer.Scheduler` property (can be done at design-time), and then set the `TIdSchedulerOfThread.ThreadClass` property (must be done at runtime, before the server is activated) to a `TIdThreadWithTask`-derived class that overrides the virtual `BeginExecute()` and `AfterExecute()` methods.

```pascal
type
  TMyThreadWithTask = class(TIdThreadWithTask)
  protected
    procedure BeforeExecute; override;
    procedure AfterExecute; override;
  end;

procedure TMyThreadWithTask.BeforeExecute;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThreadWithTask.AfterExecute;
begin
  inherited;
  CoUninitialize();
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSchedulerOfThreadDefault1.ThreadClass := TMyThreadWithTask;
end;
```

<sup>1: at least until https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/6 is implemented in a future version of Indy.</sup>